# apt-get update fails to update mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apt-get

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` in Ubuntu 14.04.2 I keep getting this message at the end. I've just been ignoring it but I'm worried that I'm not getting all of the updates I should because of it. How should I fix this?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'utilities-1.4/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config
```

Connector-Python >> connector-python-2.0 >> Apply

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the repository "https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal mysql-apt-config".

Software & Updates -> Other Software -> select it, and remove it or uncheck it.